# discord.js Bot spams DMs if a user DMs the bot

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I was recently finishing up coding my bot but one of my friends noticed this bug where you can use commands in its DMs, and it ultimately crashed the bot. So I tried using the following code to fix  the bug :

```
client.on('message', message => {

  if (message.channel.type == 'dm') {
    message.reply('Server commands only!')
  }
```

And when anyone DMs the bot, the bot spams their DMs instead of sending a single message. I tried changing the `message.reply('Server commands only!')` to `return message.reply('Server commands only!')` but it seemed to not work.

Comment: When the bot sends a message it emits the same event resulting in recursion. You should make sure `message.author.bot` is false before sending anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're falling into a message loop. Look at it this way

```
client.on('message', message => {
   // On every message, if it's a dm, send a message
   if (message.channel.type == 'dm') {
    // The bot is sending a message, which itself triggers a message event, which then triggers the bot to send the message again since it's a dm, and so on...
    message.reply('Server commands only!')
  }
}
```

The bot is detecting it's own message, which in return fires the message event, and since it's also in a dm, causes the bot to yet again send a message. This loop will continue on forever. The way to prevent this is to check if the user is a bot using

```
if (message.author.bot) return;
```

Your final code:

```
client.on('message', message => {

  if (message.author.bot) return;
  if (message.channel.type == 'dm') {
    return message.reply('Server commands only!')
  }
```

The bot will now ignore its own message.

Comment: oh sorry for my mistake, and thanks a lot for helping me! But I'm able to use the bot commands in its DMs. Any fix for that?

Comment: Use the return statement inside your if block, doing `return message.channel.send('Server commands only!');` will cause the bot to end it's current instance after sending the message. I now show this in ny edited answer